# TensorFlow как сохранить картинку из 4D тензора?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Есть результат

```
pred = sess.run()
```

`pred` - 4D тензор, (1, 128, 160, 1), float32

Пытаюсь сохранить, но tf.image.encode_jpeg требует на вход 3D тензор и int8

```
enc = tf.image.encode_jpeg(pred)
fname = tf.constant('1.jpg')
fwrite = tf.write_file(fname, enc)
```

Нужно как-то отрезать одно измерение?

Comment: Что возвращает: `type(pred)`?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
enc = tf.image.encode_jpeg(pred[0])
```

Comment: Ошибки пропали, но файл на диск не пишет. я делаю reshapedData = tf.cast(pred[0], tf.uint8) и enc = tf.image.encode_jpeg(reshapedData)